# Passing variables from cs to javascript

Tags: c#, asp.net

i'm my code behind of my web application, i have this method associated to the event click

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

      string pagFinal = "this is a test";

      ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "variable", "<script language=javascript> var direction = <%=pagFinal%> </script>");

}
```

but when i see the html generated doesn't appear's the javascript why i'm doing wrong. Thanks

Comment: You've embedded server side code in your JS snippet. That Will however be outputted literally

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can directly replace the variable value in your code -

```
ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "variable", "<script language=javascript> var direction = '" + pagFinal + "'; </script>");
```